# How to duplicate frames if appsrc is pushing too slow to keep frame rate up?

Tags: java, opencv, ffmpeg, gstreamer

I am using Java with GStreamer wrapped by OpenCV. The application does the following:

1. One GStreamer pipeline, that receives frames from an IP Camera (RTSP stream with 30fps) and outputs OpenCV Mats
   `"rtspsrc location=rtsp://localhost:8554/looping-sample latency=500 protocols=udp buffer-mode=auto ! rtph264depay ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 max-threads=2 ! videoconvert ! video/x-raw,format=BGR ! appsink max-buffers=0 drop=true sync=false"`
2. On those Mats, deep learning models infer and draw stuff on it (This might be slow, like 100ms or sth)
3. Another GStreamer pipeline wrapped by OpenCV at the 30fps (extracted by the RTSP stream), that receives those Mats and publishes an RTMP stream for a MediaServer
   `"appsrc ! videoconvert ! nvh264enc bitrate=3000 ! h264parse ! flvmux ! rtmpsink location=test"`

Now, the problem is, that the OpenCV VideoWriter is configured to be 30fps but the appsrc is only pushing at e.g. 7fps, so the RTMP stream will not be classified as valid by the MediaServer.
Previously, I used OpenCV and FFFMPEG and the default VideoWriter just duplicated the last frame to keep up the pre-defined framerate, so the stream is laggy but works.

How can I achieve this with a GStreamer pipeline?

TLDR: The OpenCV VideoWriter is configured to be 30fps but appsrc is only pushing with 7-10fps, how can I adaptively duplicate frames to keep the 30fps in the RTMP stream sink?

I tried stuff like adding "appsrc ! videorate ..." to the pipeline, so that videorate keeps up the framerate, but that did not work

Comment: afaik, `videorate` is the right thing, but I don't know to use it correctly.

Comment: Indeed, it seems that videorate and setting the framerate in the pipeline definition overrides the fps as passed to OpenCV's VideoWriter.open() function

Comment: gstreamer docs say: "This element takes an incoming stream of *timestamped* video frames. It will produce a perfect stream that matches the source pad's framerate." Maybe that's the problem. OpenCV probably doesnt use/provide any timestamps OR assigns static timestamps according to the specified fps?

Comment: Yes, that seems to be the issue. 
I solved it now, by explicitly setting the fps in the pipeline definition like so:
! videoconvert ! videorate ! video/x-raw,framerate=25/1 !

I just set a dummy fps in videowriter.open, but the fps is set eventually defined in the pipeline.

Thanks for your input!

Comment: BTW, I had to set emit-signals=true in the appsink for the first pipeline to drop frames from the RTSP stream in order to prevent a delay from happening